# Would teleportation be allowed?

Tags: halacha, technology, science

Suppose 'teleportation' like the transporter in star trek - where you are disassembled atom by atom, and reassembled in another location -  becomes a reality. It will then likely become the most ubiquitous way for people to travel around - to/from work, on vacation, anywhere.

We can also imagine this teleportation being done slowly in parts, where let's say a leg is disassembled then reassembled elsewhere, followed by an arm, followed by bones and organs in some sequence, followed by small portions of the brain. In this way, there may be no single point in time at which the original is 'dead' and the copy is 'alive' - or at least no line that can be drawn unambiguously.

What would halacha say about it? Would it consider it as murder, since the original is disassembled? Or maybe it'd be ok since the person is recreated elsewhere and continues to live there, and moreover from a subjective viewpoint it would feel like a continuous experience - not unlike going to sleep on an airplane and waking up in another country.

Comment: This is a fascinating question, however, until we get there we won't know the details necessary for Halachic ruling. Similarly, the Halachah hasn't dealt yet with the basic question of identity. The only way of identifying a person as Moshe is when two witnesses say that. That's a long way to teleportation.

Comment: This is too speculative as the method cannot be determined. For example stepping through a "door" is different from disassembly and reassembly.

Comment: @AlBerko : Are there any guidelines around how those two witnesses determine it's the same identity? That's the real question - what is it about a person that uniquely determines it's them.

Comment: @sabbahillel : Perhaps the example of teleportation was a bit ahead of its time, so consider a sooner implementable (and more detailed) scenario : Temporarily stop and separate a person's organs (heart, brain, etc.), transport them to another location, then reattach them. Or even sooner - don't separate the organs, just temporarily stop them, transport through vast amounts of space and time, then reanimate (i.e. suspended animation).

Comment: As I mentioned I don't know of any requirements for the witnesses - they just come and say - this is Moshe. Even worse, they can only say "that man killed someone" and that would suffice. The "Torah" set this rule - whatever two witnesses testify - so be it.

Comment: (continued) However those scenarios do miss a crucial dimension of the original question (disassembly/reassembly) - if you skip disassembly, you effectively create clones, and then @AlBerko's question of identity becomes paramount. As well as a host of other metaphysical pandora's boxes, such as uniqueness of a soul and soul/body relationship.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the idea of "portation". What "portates" is the DATA, not the material. Reincarnation might be a good example of the soul detaching from the body and entering a different one. Do we call it death? Certainly. BTW I don't know of anybody that claims that would be the same man, only a copy, a clone. Here's a good article on that: https://waitbutwhy.com/2014/12/what-makes-you-you.html

Comment: @AlBerko I'm well aware of that article (it's a nice read), and yes obviously only the structural data is transmitted. Yet the article in fact explores several possibilities of what of makes 'you' (body, data, brain, continuity, etc.) and it's far from clear what the right conclusion is in the end.

Comment: https://www.leolamvaed.com/2019/08/08/transporter-for-the-soul/

Comment: @PopularIsn'tRight : Cute post, though it makes an implicit assumption that a soul has to be associated with only one body. Perhaps the clone and the original share a soul? If you graft an extra lab grown limb (or even a brain portion) to yourself, it's reasonable to assume you still have the same soul. So if go a bit further and fully duplicate yourself, the soul is now associated with the extra limb - in this case an entire body.